# Searching for exact match in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, search, exact-match

I have the below code and am working on creating a search bar with options on a table to filter through. It works perfectly, however I cannot seem to get it to search/filter for exact matches. For example, if I input 'GE' it will return all matches where words include 'GE' whilst I want only those fields where the two letters together are located.

Can anyone help me tweak my code?

```
  'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
     'Cell Range
       Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range 'Table

'Retrieve User's Search Input

  mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("Hello").Object.Text 'ActiveX Control


'Determine if user is searching for number or text
  If IsNumeric(mySearch) = True Then
    SearchString = "=" & mySearch
  Else
    SearchString = "=*" & mySearch & "*"

'Loop Through Option Buttons
  For Each myButton In sht.OptionButtons
    If myButton.Value = 1 Then
      ButtonName = myButton.Text
      Exit For
    End If
  Next myButton

'Determine Filter Field
  On Error GoTo HeadingNotFound
    myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filter Data
  DataRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=myField, _
    Criteria1:=SearchString, _
    Operator:=xlAnd

'Clear Search Field
  'sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "" 'Control Form
  sht.OLEObjects("Hello").Object.Text = "" 'ActiveX Control
  'sht.Range("A1").Value = "" 'Cell Input

Exit Sub

'ERROR HANDLERS
HeadingNotFound:
  MsgBox "The column heading [" & ButtonName & "] was not found in cells " & DataRange.Rows(1).Address & ". " & _
    vbNewLine & "Please check for possible typos.", vbCritical, "Header Name Not Found!"

End Sub
```

Comment: `SearchString = "=*" & mySearch & "*"` You are searching for anything that will contain `mySearch`.. Use `SearchString = "=" & mySearch`

Comment: Perfect - did the trick....I didn't realise that I had the search in as such. Please post your answer so that I can tick this off :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SearchString = "=*" & mySearch & "*"` You are searching for anything that will contain mySearch.

Change it to `SearchString = "=" & mySearch`